# Why did Resque choose Json over Yaml as a serialization language?

Tags: ruby, json, yaml, delayed-job, resque

We are looking to migrate from `delayed_job` to `resque` for our site, and one of the caveats I am seeing all over is that while `delayed_job` used yaml for serialization, `resque` uses json, and because of this the hash keys and etc which are symbols need to be accessed as strings, since symbols cannot be stored in json([e.g source](http://www.betaful.com/2012/11/delayedjob-to-resque/)).

My question is, if this is true, was there a reason for picking json over yaml? Or rather is there any advantage that json offers for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some JSON support by using redis hashes but I never used it and I doubt it's any useful in this case.

Resque probably uses JSON instead of YAML because it's more broad. I also found a comment on this issue about that.

> @defunkt
>
> YAML does not preserve Ruby objects better - with complicated objects
> it can serialize an object that it can't unserialize later. This is
> unacceptable.
>
> If you want symbol keys I believe YAJL has an option we could use to
> preserve the keys. Also you could trivially call symbolize_keys on an
> object if you have ActiveSupport.

https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/26